# Replicate Contact details on Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use this method of viewing details of a list item in my own development, but I cannot seem to figure out the right words to Google. I was hoping to get some help on replicating this behaviour.

My current idea is to have a fragment with a higher z than the list and put a swipe listener in the fragment. Then when it reaches a certain height make it a full screen fragment, but I'm not sure if this is the proper​way

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: may be it will hep check this link   https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: You can try native android's persistent bottom sheet https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html . If you just want that behaviour check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html . For demo check this out https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031

Comment: Thank you both so much. This is exactly what I was looking for